# Inner functions and the Taylor coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

When I study the theory of $H^p$ spaces, I know that $f \in H^\infty$ is called an inner function if $|f(e^{i\theta})|=1$ a.e. on $T$. This definition is clear. However, when I read the D. J. Newman and H. S. Shapiro's paper: $\textit{The Taylor coefficients of inner functions}$, it says that  $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ is inner if 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2=1 \quad \mbox{and}\quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \overline{a_{n+k}}=0
\end{equation*} for every $k=1,2,\ldots$. I have searched the references used in the paper and other books (e.g. Bounded Analytic Functions by Garnett, Theory of $H^p$ Spaces by Duren), I couldn't find a proof of these equations. Can anyone provide some relevant references? Or a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f=\sum a_nz^n$ and $g=\sum b_n z^n$ then $\newcommand\ip[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}$ $$\ip fg=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{it})\overline{g(e^{it}}\,dt=\sum a_n\overline{b_n}.$$

So if $f$ is an inner function and $k$ is a positive integer, then letting $g(z)=z^kf(z)$ we see $$\sum a_n\overline{a_{k+n}}=\ip fg=0.$$

For the converse, assume $||f||_2=1$ and all those other sums vanish. We have $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-ikt}|f(e^{it})|^2\,dt=0$$for $k=1,2\dots$, hence also for $k=-1,-2\dots$, and hence $|f|^2$ is constant, by a little argument about Fourier series.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich, I am sorry that the point $\langle f, z^kf\rangle=0$ is not clear to me. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I understand why $\langle f, z^kf\rangle=0$ now!